# Send parameter from view to controller via link in Grails

Tags: grails, gsp

For example, I've this string in GSP:

```
<td>${cafeeInfo.cafeeName}</td>
```

How can I send value to the controller via parameter? I know how to do it with form, but to my mind in this case better method is possible.

Comment: What's the event? Do you want the user to click a link or button?

Comment: @sebnukem, I want to click a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<g:link action="???" controller="???" params="[param1: value1]">Whatever</g:link>
```

Here is some [Documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Tags/link.html)